# WordPress shortcode for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I am working on a custom WordPress theme and need to call the $title field for each page within the footer. That field needs to be the same as the one I set as SEO title with the RankMath plugin and I solved it using this function:

```
add_shortcode('rm_title', 'rm_shortcode_title');
function rm_shortcode_title(){
    global $post;
    $title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rank_math_title', true);
    return $title;
}
```

Now, using the shortcode [rm_title] I can see the SEO title within the footer. However, this only works for classic post types (pages and posts).

What I am trying to do is to also use this shortcode for custom post types, in particular on post_type=user_ads. I've noticed that when I go into the edit screen, in addition to the post_type, there are several fields in the url. I list them here:

1. **taxonomy=custom_5662**
2. **tag_ID=480 ( this value changes for each post type )**
3. **post_type=user_ads**

The complete editing url of the individual custom post types has this structure: **https://localhost/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=custom_5662&tag_ID=XXX&post_type=user_ads**

I have tried various ways without ever being able to find a working solution, so I am kindly asking for help.

Thank you in advance for reading this.

Comment: If your admin URL is `/wp-admin/term.php` then that's not a CPT but a taxonomy. A taxonomy is associated with one or more CPTs, but it is a standalone object unto itself. RankMath may or may not work with taxonomies (I'm not familiar with that plugin) but I'd check that, first.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks a lot for the clarification. I believed that while they are two different things, there was still a way to create a working shortcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, based on the URL for editing this is a taxonomy and not a CPT, and as such the meta is stored in a different location.

To be more generic, instead of using the `global $post` object we can ask WordPress for the current "thing" using [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/). This can return several different things depending on the URL but we are (currently) only interested in posts and taxonomy terms. From that we can perform and `instance of` test and return the appropriate data.

```php
add_shortcode('rm_title', 'rm_shortcode_title');
function rm_shortcode_title(){
    $obj = get_queried_object();
    if($obj instance of WP_Post){
        return get_post_meta($obj->ID, 'rank_math_title', true);
    }

    if($obj instance of WP_Term){
        return get_term_meta($obj->term_id, 'rank_math_title', true);
    }
}
```

As noted, there's other things that might be queried that you might be interested in, too. For instance, `get_queried_object()` might return a `WP_User` object on author pages if you are using those, and if so you'd want to use [`get_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/).

It can also return a `WP_Post_Type` object on archive pages, however that doesn't have a direct `get_XYZ_meta` function, and instead, if your plugin supports it, it is probably somewhere in the options table.

Also, I have no idea if you term code actually works. You might need to run `var_dump(get_term_meta($obj->term_id));` with only one parameter to see what is really in the table for that object.

Comment: Thank you again for your comprehensive answer. I have tested your code and it only works for every wp_post, as far as wp_terms are concerned the situation has not changed and I still do not see the desired content. Running the suggested dump, this is what I got:

Comment: array (size=7) 'parent_terms' => array (size=1) 0 => string '' (length=0) 'field_dependencies' => array (size=1) 0 => string '' (length=0) 'search_form_placeholder' => array (size=1) 0 => string '' (length=0) 'custom_model_template' => array (size=1) 0 => string '0' (length=1) 'card_hide' => array (size=1) 0 => string '0' (length=1) 'label_color' => array (size=1) 0 => string '' (length=0) 'label_bg_color' => array (size=1) 0 => string '' (length=0)

Comment: Can you confirm that when you edit a taxonomy term you are seeing the Rank Math options? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rank-math-do-not-display-on-custom-taxonomies-cpt-ui/

Comment: Yes, I see the rank math options when i'm editing a taxonomy term and the reason I need that shortcode is because each taxonomy term have a custom SEO title in the Rank Math options.

Comment: Chris, your code works perfectly! I couldn't hook up the seo title because it was auto-generated by Rank Math according to keywords and very specific criteria given by me for each term, so I don't have to write it manually. Using this method, RankMath does not fill in the field inside the term but only hook it at code level in the <title> field. However, if I try to write it manually in the field provided for each term, it becomes visible in the front-end. Now, as there are not many terms, I will enter the titles manually. Thank you very much for your help!